# Memory heavy use in wildfly swarm

Tags: java, wildfly, microservices, wildfly-swarm

I have a problem using wildfly swarm for build micro service in java. My main problem is the excess use memory. When wildfly is deployed this consume almost 500 mb of memory. Someone have a possible solution for resolve it?

thanks!

Comment: Can you give us some ideas about what it is your application does?  How many swarm "fractions" are you using (i.e., JPA, EJB, etc.)?

Comment: bom-all
wildfly-swarm-plugin
junit
jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec
cdi-api
postgresql
swagger-annotations
swagger-jaxrs
jersey-media-json-jackson
jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec
logback-classic
lombok
postgresql
commons-beanutils
commons-lang3

Comment: what kind of memory? heap? native? Is this before full GC or after? try connecting with jconsole to the app and see what are exact memory usages.

Comment: That hardly seems like a "micro" service.  500MB honestly doesn't seem too bad given things like swagger and ejb.  Are you running on an extremely small machine?

Comment: the micro services run on docker in ecs used on AWS. But if i compare with other technology like Vertx the difference I really hard. What think about it?

Comment: So that is yet another variable. What kind of Docker base image? A full Ubuntu base with just openjdk is a bit over 300MB on my machine. Add Wildfly swarm with the very large set of inclusions you have and it's pretty easy to hit 500MB.  I happen to use Wildfly Swarm in ECS on AWS and yes, the image sizes are about as you describe and yes, it takes some memory.  If there solutions that can do everything you're getting with Wildfly and are more in line with what you're looking for, I'd use them instead.

Comment: Thank you guys for all answer. Have a nice day.

Comment: The amount of memory WF Swarm consumes is something that we're in the process of looking into further